# Not able to resolve Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I am trying to execute a Groovy Script in SoapUI 5.3.0 which imports a jar file compiled in JDK 1.8. However, since SoapUI 5.3.0 is using 1.7; I am getting an exception "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0".

I have tried to follow the below link, but was not able to solve it.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127289/discussion-between-rao-and-user5653362

I understand I need to modify soapui.bat in C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0/bin folder; so SoapUI starts using Java 1.8; but not exactly sure which property to change.

My soaupui.bat looks like below:

*

```
@echo off
set SOAPUI_HOME=%~dp0
if exist "%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin" goto SET_BUNDLED_JAVA
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%" goto SET_SYSTEM_JAVA
echo JAVA_HOME is not set, unexpected results may occur.
echo Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
goto SET_SYSTEM_JAVA
:SET_BUNDLED_JAVA
set JAVA=%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin\java
goto END_SETTING_JAVA
:SET_SYSTEM_JAVA
set JAVA=java
:END_SETTING_JAVA
rem init classpath
set OLDDIR=%CD%
cd /d %SOAPUI_HOME%
set CLASSPATH=%SOAPUI_HOME%soapui-5.3.0.jar;%SOAPUI_HOME%..\lib\*
"%JAVA%" -cp "%CLASSPATH%" com.eviware.soapui.tools.JfxrtLocator > %TEMP%\jfxrtpath
set /P JFXRTPATH= < %TEMP%\jfxrtpath
del %TEMP%\jfxrtpath
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JFXRTPATH%
rem JVM parameters, modify as appropriate
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties "-Dsoapui.home=%SOAPUI_HOME%\" -splash:SoapUI-Spashscreen.png
if "%SOAPUI_HOME%" == "" goto START
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.ext.libraries="%SOAPUI_HOME%ext"
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.ext.listeners="%SOAPUI_HOME%listeners"
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.ext.actions="%SOAPUI_HOME%actions"
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.library.path="%SOAPUI_HOME%\"
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dwsi.dir="%SOAPUI_HOME%..\wsi-test-tools"
rem uncomment to disable browser component
rem    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.browser.disabled="true"
:START
rem ********* run soapui ***********
"%JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI %*
cd /d %OLDDIR%
```

- 

The path variable is as follows:

```
G:......;E:\Learning\JAVA\jdk1.8\bin
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install Java 8.

In the launcher (`.bat`), choose the right path.

The line `if exist "%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin" goto SET_BUNDLED_JAVA` indicates that a JRE may comes with SoapUI.

The next line: `if exist "%JAVA_HOME%" goto SET_SYSTEM_JAV` is interesting but the two lines: `:SET_SYSTEM_JAVA
set JAVA=java` doesn't use it. I suggest to:

- remove the jre provided by SOAPUI
- `set JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java` in line 12

Comment: I have Java 8 installed in my system. Could you please indicate which property I need to change so that it picks 1.8?

Comment: I have a follow up question though. When I start SoapUI from command prompt (soapui.bat), the version of Java (under Help>System Properties) is showing as 1.8 and executes Groovy code as expected.  But if I open SoapUI using the icon which is present under C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0>bin folder, the Java version under Help>System Properties is showing 1.7; and obviously reproducing the problem of major.minor version which I was having earlier. Any idea how do make sure that SoapUI icon also opens SoapUI with proper java version (1.8)?

Comment: To see the code under the icon, right click on it and select "properties"
You may identify which launcher is used by reading the fields.
I use Linux, not Windows, sorry, I can't do more.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to:

1. Install whatever Java version you want for your platform, including correctly setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable.
2. Rename `$SOAPUI_HOME/jre` to something like `$SOAPUI_HOME/jre.ignore`.
3. Start SoapUI. You can check the SoapUI log, to verify the correct version of Java is being used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall the old version of [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/).

And please check the latest version 5.4.0 of soapUI from [here](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release.html).

I faced the same issue and solved by trying with the latest version which is working with Java 1.8.

Hope this will help you !!